# Fetching data using Ajax got Undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, undefined, codeigniter-3

I am stuck on getting result from database via Ajax. id="view_errorcode" is working, but id="view_vlokasi" is not and just showing UNDEFINED. Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong in my code?

```
$('#showdata').on('click', '.item-info', function(){
  var tid = $(this).attr('data');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'get',
    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>RepeatProblem/infoReprob',
    data: {tid:tid},
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      var vlokasi = '<span style="font-size:22px;color:green">'+data.lokasi+'</span>';
      var html = '';
      var i;
      for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        html +='<p style="font-size:18px;color:black"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> '+data[i].lokasi+' '+data[i].updated_at+'<br>'+data[i].ketprob+'</p>';
      }

      $('#infoModal').modal('show');
      $('#view_lokasi').html(vlokasi); // showing UNDEFINED
      $('#view_errorcode').html(html); // Working
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('Gagal Info Kode Error!');
    }
  });
});
```

The ajax call returns the following json

```
[{"tid":"550250","ketprob":"1","updated_at":"15-09-2018 19:39","lokasi":"ERA MART TENGKAWANG"},{"tid":"550250","ketprob":"2","updated_at":"15-09-2018 19:39","lokasi":"ERA MART TENGKAWANG"},{"tid":"550250","ketprob":"3","updated_at":"15-09-2018 19:39","lokasi":"ERA MART TENGKAWANG"},{"tid":"550250","ketprob":"4","updated_at":"15-09-2018 19:37","lokasi":"ERA MART TENGKAWANG"}]
```

Comment: Can anybody help me about this issue, why is "data.lokasi" shows UNDEFINED while the "data[i].lokasi" works? Please

Comment: Because `data` is an array, evidently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like It's object array, so you can't access to lokasi property while you will not loop array. Try this:

```
var lokasi;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
lokasi = data[i].lokasi;
...
```

Or you can get specific element from item like

```
data[0].lokasi
```

or

```
data[n].lokasi
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to check the received data, I am new in JS. Thanks

Comment: Add a `console.log(data);` statement, then check the console in your browser developer tools.

Comment: @badsyntax Here is the log:

{tid: "550250", ketprob: "1", updated_at: "15-09-2018 19:39", lokasi: "ERA MART TENGKAWANG"}

Comment: @ShotaNoniashvili [{"tid":"550250","ketprob":"1","updated_at":"15-09-2018 19:39","lokasi":"ERA MART TENGKAWANG"},{"tid":"550250","ketprob":"2","updated_at":"15-09-2018 19:39","lokasi":"ERA MART TENGKAWANG"},{"tid":"550250","ketprob":"3","updated_at":"15-09-2018 19:39","lokasi":"ERA MART TENGKAWANG"},{"tid":"550250","ketprob":"4","updated_at":"15-09-2018 19:37","lokasi":"ERA MART TENGKAWANG"}]

Comment: @ShotaNoniashvili That works! I need to learn about to loop array.. Thank you so much